# PHP CURL error : unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, tls1.2

The error is occurring only in production  But in the local environment, it is working fine.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL    , $url                  );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array( 'Content-Type: application/json' ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT            , 60                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER     , 1                                         );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST      , 'GET'                 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION     , TRUE                  );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION       , CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1                     );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO           , true      );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE            , 1         );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,$ssl_cert_path);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEY,$ssl_key_path);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAPATH,$ca_path );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO, $ca_path.$peer_cert );
        
$result = null; $httpCode = null;
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: And the difference between production and local environment is what? The problems might be caused by having a different CA store (your unknown `$ca_path` setting - and the content of the file behind it) or a server providing a different certificate. Too much unknowns here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich `$ca_path` is the path of a file where I have stored Ca certificates. The script is working fine with the same ca certificate in my local system. But in production, the problem is occurring. If the file contains the wrong CA/Itermiadetes certificates then the peer validation should returns errors from my local system also.

Comment: @user7540720: Have you verified that you get exactly the same certificate in production and test? Have you verified that the files described by `$ca_path` have exactly the same content on production and test?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes I have checked both two files are identically the same. Is there anything related to settings in php.ini?

Comment: @user7540720: again -  Have you verified that you get exactly the same certificate in production and test?

Comment: Also, CURLOPT_CAPATH should specify a directory not a file - is the content of the directory the same on both systems? And CURLOPT_CAINFO should be the file, so it should be `$ca_path.$peer_cert` where the content is the same and accessible and readable on both systems.